# How can I import social media buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have just started coding and want to import social media buttons to my website. I thought about just adding pictures to my website and make them buttons. Is that the proper way to do it or is there a better way, like plugins for jQuery or anything like that ?

Comment: do you want to integrate social media buttons like fb icon with count, tweet count etc. in your website?

Comment: try http://www.addthis.com/ , http://www.sharethis.com/

Comment: well yes a facebook button that counts and shows the amount of likes or followers i have. Clicking on he button should result on loading my facebook page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve is 'http://www.addthis.com/'. You can even custom image size / social media icons / social media name etc...